# Finding the eigenvalues for each value of $a \in \mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 & 0 & a \\ 0 & 2a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a+2 \end{bmatrix}$$ For each value of $a \in \mathbb R$, find the eigenvalues of $A$.

I thought it should be whenever $\ a$ makes the determinant of $A$ zero so it should be $\ 0, -2, $ but apparently the answers are $\ -1,0,2 $ which I don't understand why?

$\ a = -1 , 2, \ \det (A) \not = 0 $

Comment: If the question is `find for each value of a, the eigen values of A` then the answer can't be $-1,0,2$. This makes no sense for now.

Comment: this is upper triangular matrix so the eigen values will be the diagnol entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is

> find for each value of $\ a $, the eigen values of $\ A $

then the answer is $a^2, 2a, a+2$ since $A$ is triangular.

If the answer is

> $-1,0,2$

then the question is "find for which value of $a$ the matrix $A$ has repeated eigenvalues."

Comment: Because $a^2=2a$ happens if and only if …; $a^2=a+2$ happens if and only if …; $2a=a+2$ happens if and only if … (Good catch!)

Comment: Yes you are right about rephrasing the question. But still how did you find the values for a ??

Comment: @bm1125 since the eigenvalues are $a^2, 2a$ and $a+2$, you have three equations to solve as indicated in egreg's comment above.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\det(A- \lambda I)=(a^2-\lambda)(2a-\lambda)(a+2- \lambda)$.

Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ are: $a^2,2a$ and $a+2$.

Answer (score 1):

$A^{2}-a^{2}I,A^{2}-(a+2)I$ adn $A^{2}-2aI$  all have one row of zeros so these are singular and the eigen values are $a^{2},a+2$ and $2a$.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues of a matrix are usually computed by finding the values of $\lambda$ such that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. The determinant of $A$ is not relevant.

The answer will be three expressions that would in general contain $a$, so I do not see how they can be -1, 0 and 2.